# global not being modified correctly in async for loop

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, async-await, discord

Scenario: Live updates from twitter stream to discord server using peonytwitter and discordpy. Occasionally, we need to slow down the tweets to avoid spoilers (twitter is ahead of live radio).

I have an async for tweet in stream loop, as a running task

```
async def twat(bot,totrack,outputChannel):
    ctx = pclient.stream.statuses.filter.post(follow=totrack)
        async with ctx as stream:
            async for tweet in stream:
                ...
                global tweetdelay
                await async.sleep(tweetdelay)
                print("tweetdelay is set to {}".format(tweetdelay))
                await bot.send_message(outputChannel,embed=em)

bot.loop.create_task(twat(bot,"123,456",Output1))
bot.loop.create_task(twat(bot,"789,1011,1213",Output2))
```

I then have a secondary function which is supposed to change the tweetdelay variable in the already running task.

```
@commands.command(aliases = ["tweetdelay"])
async def matchmode(self,delay = "0"):
    if delay.isdigit() == True:
        delay = int(delay)
        global tweetdelay
        tweetdelay = delay
        print(tweetdelay)
```

When the matchmode/tweetdelay function is fired via the command, I get

> > > 120

However, when the next tweet occurs, I still get

> > > tweetdelay is set to 0

So I'm obviously misinterpreting how to check global variables during a loop.

The first option I thought of would be to just figure out a way to kill the loop and restart it by feeding it an extra parameter as twat(bot,totrack,delay,outputChannel) but the problem with this is twitter's 420 enhance your calm status code will block the reconnects if the function is used too often (e.g. when fine tuning the delay). Can someone please give me a nudge in the right direction of what I should be doing instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
async def check_delay():
    global tweetdelay
    return tweetdelay

twat():
    ...
    tweetdelay = await check_delay()
    await async.sleep(tweetdelay)
```